# Why are cascaded entities from a non-cascaded entity persisted on a save operation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've been using Hibernate on and off for a very long time. Today I experienced something which I can't explain. I saved an entity that had no cascading to a related entity. The related, non-cascaded entity had a relationship to some new/unpersisted entities with cascading, and although their entity models weren't updated after persistence, they were saved to the database!

Here's the gist of the entities in play:

- A plan has 1+ steps, and a step belongs to exactly 1 plan
- A plan has 0+ log events
- A step has 0+ log events
- A log event has either an associated step or plan, but not both
- There is no cascading between a plan and its steps
- Cascade = ALL for plan => logs
- Cascade = ALL for step => logs
- No cascading is specified for plan => steps

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram, I think]

When our @Transactional service calls planRepository.save(plan), I expect that updates to the plan and its associated logs will be saved, but any changes to the step and its logs will NOT be saved. However, what I've observed is that the step's newly-created logs ARE saved. The steps already existed; I'm not sure whether that is an important detail or not. All of the logs are new.

If I use EntityManager to create a "from Log" query, it'll provide me with the persisted logs for the steps. However, if I return the plan to the calling method (the controller in this case), or fetch the plan directly from Hibernate, the steps' logs don't have a primary key, whereas the plan's logs do (which is what I would expect).

I'm surprised that Hibernate is saving the steps' logs. What kind of voodoo is going on? Is this configurable?

Comment: I don't follow. You modified a persistent entity, why would the changes **not** be saved?

Comment: There's no cascading from Plan to Step, but there is cascading from Step to Log. When I save the Plan, it saves the Step's Logs, even without cascading? Furthermore, even though the Logs are saved, their IDs aren't populated. If I add cascading in, the IDs *are* populated, which is what I expect.

At the point of call, the Step *is* persisted, but the Logs *are not*. Without cascading, I don't expect the logs to be persisted when I save the Plan

Comment: Let me repeat: changes to persistent entities are always saved. Does `Plan.steps` contain persistent entities? Did you make changes to the objects in that collection? No, this behaviour is not configurable

Comment: Let me repeat: There's no cascading from Plan to Step, but there is cascading from Step to Log. When I save the Plan, it saves the Step's Logs, even without cascading? Furthermore, even though the Logs are saved, their IDs aren't populated. If I add cascading in, the IDs are populated, which is what I expect. At the point of call, the Step is persisted, but the Logs are not. Without cascading, I don't expect the logs to be persisted when I save the Plan

Comment: 'The steps already existed; I'm not sure whether that is an important detail or not.' Yes, this is a crucial detail. The `Step`s are persistent entities, which means any changes you make to them are tracked by Hibernate and persisted by the end of the transaction. It doesn't matter how you gained access to them: by calling `em.find()`, a query, or by virtue of them being associated to another entity. If you make changes to a persistent entity, those changes will be saved

Comment: Also, 'If I use EntityManager to create a "from Log" query, it'll provide me with the persisted logs for the steps' - no surprise about that, because the context is flushed before executing a query. Try using `FlushMode.COMMIT` instead. 'If I (...) fetch the plan directly from Hibernate, the steps' logs don't have a primary key - again, no surprise, because the `Plan` is already in the context, so Hibernate is giving you the exact same object instance which is not yet synchronized with the data store